# Mysql inner query not working

Tags: sql, mysql

```
    $sql= "select 
            tblservergroup.id,
            tblservergroup.groupname,

            if(tblservergroup.defserverpaid='0', '0', select concat(tblservers.ipaddress, ' (', tblservers.name, ')' ) as defaultserverpaiddesc from tblservers where tblservers.id=tblservergroup.defserverpaid),
            if(tblservergroup.defserverfree='0', '0', select concat(tblservers.ipaddress, ' (', tblservers.name, ')' ) as defaultserverfreedesc from tblservers where tblservers.id=tblservergroup.defserverfree),      

            tblservergroup.note
            from tblservergroup
";
```

This similar concept can be done in MSSQL, but when I write it in mysql, it shows error. Help.

Comment: Can you post the table schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on subqueries, you can do this:

```
SELECT
    tblservergroup.id,
    tblservergroup.groupname,
    tblservergroup.note,
    IF(defserverpaid='0', '0', (SELECT concat(ipaddress, ' (', name, ')') FROM tblservers WHERE id=defserverpaid)) AS defaultserverpaiddesc,
    IF(defserverfree='0', '0', (SELECT concat(ipaddress, ' (', name, ')') FROM tblservers WHERE id=defserverfree)) AS defaultserverfreedesc
FROM
    tblservergroup
```

I'd suggest to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT
    tblservergroup.id,
    tblservergroup.groupname,
    tblservergroup.note,
    IF(defserverpaid='0', '0', concat(ts1.ipaddress, ' (', ts1.name, ')')) as defaultserverpaiddesc
    IF(defserverfree='0', '0', concat(ts2.ipaddress, ' (', ts2.name, ')')) as defaultserverfreedesc
FROM
    tblservergroup
    LEFT JOIN tblservers ts1 ON ts1.id=defserverpaid
    LEFT JOIN tblservers ts2 ON ts2.id=defserverfree
```

Ideally also store `NULL` instead of `0` in `defserverpaid`/`defserverfree`, and add foreign key constraints.

Comment: thnx, I finally found that there's some mistake in my syntax.